# what should i put event on onclick?

Tags: javascript

```
<img src="image1.png" onclick="handler(this.src)" />

function handler(event, handler_src){
  if(onClickOn){
    companyJes(handler_src);
  }else{
    event.preventDefault(); // don't do anything
    event.stopPrpagation(); // really don't do anything

    return false; //make sure you don't do anything
  }
}
```

on the onclick `handler(what should i put this ?, this.src);` what should i put variable on onclick to replace the event ?

i tested `handler(event, this.src);` but it didt work.

Comment: could you tell us a little bit more about what you are trying to do?

Comment: Wait, what? `this` in event handlers are _already_ bound to the HTML element. There's no need to pass it in directly to the handler. Just make your event handler have one argument for `event`, and that's all you need.

Comment: cant i need the this.src too to trigger something.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the event object in the handler. E.g:

```
handler(event)
```

Because "this" will the HTML element which called the handler function

See the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7w84g9ro/)